# cant create GA4 custom event based on measurement protocol events

Tags: google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

im trying to create custom event from (GA4 => admin => events => create an event) when a purchase happens

so im firing a purchase event using measurement protocol with this example object

```
{
  "client_id": {{clint_id}},
  "user_id": {{user_id}},
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "purchase",
      "params": {
        "value": {{value}},
        "user_plan":{{plan}},
        "currency": "USD",
        "transaction_id": {{transaction-id}},
        "items": [
          {
            "item_id": {{item-id}},
            "item_name": {{item-name}}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

i have no issue with this event im receiving it on GA4 and i can see it in realtime and other reports

the issue is when i try to create a custom event for some specific case for example if user_plan = "testing_plan"

in the custom event(admin->events->new event) i have created a new event with

```
parameter = event_name
value = purchase 
parameter = user_plan 
value contains testing_plan
```

and this event is not working i cant see it any where
i didnt find any specific documentation for this case

if anyone knows what's going on please help

Note: if i sent the purchase event using gtag the custom event will work

i tried to change event_name to "en" (chat GPT suggestion) ,but also didn't work

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm also encountering the same issue with GA4

Comment: MP requires you to also send `engagement_time_msec` and `user_agent` for custom events.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Create Event not Modify Event work with Measurement Protocol.

The 2 features are actually executed on the client side from what I gather (as part of the GA4 script that the user downloads when browsing a site). Measurement Protocol doesn't have any of that and is just a very direct way of injecting events straight into GA4.

There are no processing pipelines attached to it with GA4 itself.